# Android: Facebook login state when no connection

Tags: android, facebook

I need to know if I am logged in or not to Facebook even when I don't have a connection.

When using the Facebook login button, even when I have no connection, it knows to display the label "Log out" and not "Log in" if I am logged in. How does it do that?

Any ideas about how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain one `SharedPreference` say `isFbLogin`, Now when user logs in from Facebook, set it to true, and when user logs out set it to false.

Now each time when your app is launched, check if this preference is true, if yes, show logout button else show login button.

Read more about SharedPreferences [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)